# git push suddenly taking forever

Tags: git

I am using git with `overleaf`. I changed one minor file and committed, and now all of a sudden `git push` is taking forever. It used to take about 20 seconds for a push, but the current one has taken over 20 minutes.

Here is the output of `git push`.

```
(base) macbook-pro:figures dzdang$ git push --verbose
Pushing to https://git.overleaf.com/some_identifying_url
Counting objects: 417, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (416/416), done.
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)  
Writing objects: 100% (417/417), 99.39 MiB | 241.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 417 (delta 185), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (185/185)
remote: Updating references: 100% (1/1)
To https://git.overleaf.com/some_identifying_url
   c416a03..e8d4ed7  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
```

Could someone advise me a way to see what is taking so long during the push process? I tried using the `--verbose` flag as shown above, but I don't see any useful information.

Comment: Why are you writing 99MiB worth of data into Git?  Did you commit a binary?

Comment: @Makoto No, there are a lot of figures that I committed. But the figures have been there for the past couple weeks, and it wasn't taking this long to push before.

Comment: What do you mean by “Figures”?